# fork and IPC mechanism

Tags: linux, fork, ipc, pipe, shared-memory

I'm writing a mono-thread memory heavy *proof of concept* application.
This application doesn't manipulate much data per se, will mainly load GBs of data and then do some data analysis on it.

I don't want to manage concurrency via MT implementation, don't want to have to implement *locks* (i.e. mutexes, spinlocks, ...) so I've decided this time around to use the dear old *fork()*.
On Linux, where memory is *CoW*, I should be able to efficiently analyse same datasets without having to copy them explicitly and with simple parallel mono-thread logic (again, this is a *proof of concept*).

Now that I spawn child processes, with *fork()* is very easy to setup input parameters for a *sub-task* (*sub-process* in this case), but then I have to get back the results to the main process. And sometimes these results are **10s of GB large**. All the IPC mechanisms I have in mind are:

- PIPEs/Sockets (and then *epoll* equivalent to wait for results in a mono-thread fashion)
- Hybrid PIPEs/Shared Memory (*epoll* equivalent to wait for results with reference to Shared Memory, then copy data from Shared Memory into parent process, destroy Shared Memory)

What else could I use? Apart the obvious "go multi-thread", I *really* would like to leverage the *CoW* and single-thread multi-process architecture for this *proof of concept*. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some experimenting the conclusion I got to is the following:

1. When a child process has to communicate with parent, before spawning such child process I create a segment of shared memory (i.e. 16 MB)
2. if coordination is needed a semaphore is created in sh mem segment
3. Then upon forking, I *pipe2* with *nonblocking* sockets so child can notify parent when some data is available
4. The pipe `fd` is then used into *epoll*
5. *epoll* is used as `Level Triggered` so I can interleave requests if the child processes are *really* fast in sending data
6. The segment of shared memory is used to communicate data directly if the structures are `pod` or with simple `template<...>` binary read/write functions if those are not

I believe this is a good solution.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a regular file.

Parent process could wait for the child process (to analyse the data on memory and then write to file its result and) to exit and once it does, you must be able to read data from the file. As you mentioned, input parameter is not a problem, you could just specify the file name to write to in one of the input parameters. This way, there is no locking required or except for wait() on exit status of child process.

I wonder if each of your child processes return 10s of GB large data, this way it is much better to use regular files, as you will have enough time to process each of the child process's result. But is this 10GBs data shared across child processes? If that was the case, you would have preferred to use locks, so I assume it isn't.

Comment: I'm using shared memory between child and parent process (serializing/deserializing in binary form), and is the fastest IPC. I can transfer large quantities of data in short space, is working fine so far. I would think using the filesystem would just slow down things and rely on the disk possibly. And it wouldn't solve the problem of blocking the parent process too long whilst reading the file.

Comment: You are right, shared memory is fastest. And file r/w is slow. But other than that, you can use files the same way as shared memory. Blocking parent process is not necessary, I wasn't sure how you notify of data availability to the parent process even with Shared memory. Anyway you have found your solution I guess.